# Classic sound mixer

Tags: c++, windows-xp, audio, mixer

Good day, everyone!

I write a sound mixer and I need getting under sound device capabilities control such as I can got with windows mixer. I can manipulate general volume and mute states of mixer, but I can't gain an access to other options, for example: my system has Realtek HD Audio mixer and it makes following controls:

- synthesizer: volume, mute and balance control;
- front: volume, mute and balance control;
- rear: volume, mute and balance control;
- subwoofer: volume, mute and balance control;
  and so on.

My OS is Windows XP, so I use a standard mmsystem library. it takes me to find all sound devices and to get a list controls that i can got. But list has only volume and mute controls.
What do I want to come at capabilities of sound mixer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what functions did you use to list your output ? did you use only the wave* set of function ?

have you tried the mixer API ? the documentation for those functions is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756704%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and more informations may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742869%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: yes, i use mixer API and i found how to decide my problem, thanks!